# using grep in single-line files to find the number of occurrences of a word/pattern

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have json files in the current directory, and subdirectories.   All the files have a single line of content.
I want to a list of all files that contain the word `XYZ`, and the number of times it occurs in that file.
I want to print the list according to the following format:
`file_name pattern_occurence_times` 
It should look something like:

```
.\x1\x2\file1.json 3
.\x1\file3.json 2
```

The problem is that `grep` counts the NUMBER of *lines* containing `XYZ`, not the number of occurrences.
Since the whole content of the files is always contained in *a single line*, the count is always 1 (if the pattern occurs in the file).
I used this command for that:

```
find . -type f -name "*.json" -exec grep --files-with-match -i 'xyz' {} \; -exec grep -wci 'xyz' {} \;
```

I wrote a python code, and it works, but I would like to know if there is any way of doing that using `find` and `grep` or any other command line tools.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical approach to this problem is the pipeline `grep -o regex file | wc -l`. However, to execute a pipeline in `find`'s `-exec` you have to run a shell (e.g. `sh -c ...` ). But all these things together will only print the number of matches, not the file names. Also, files with no matches have to be filtered out.

Because of all of this I think a single `awk` command would be preferable:

```
find ... -type f -exec awk '{$0=tolower($0); c+=gsub(/xyz/,"")}
                            END {if(c>0) print FILENAME " " c}' {} \;
```

Here the `tolower($0)` emulates `grep`'s `-i` option. Make sure to write your search pattern `xyz` only in lowercase.

If you want to combine this with subsequent filters in `find` you can add `else exit 1` at the end of the last `awk` block to continue (inside `find`) only with the printed files.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it would be faster.

Comment: @oguzismail it works faster but when I put `if(count>3)` it doesn't have any effect it prints even less than 3 times occurrence!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-o` option of `grep`, e.g. in conjunction with `wc`, e.g.

```
find . -name "*.json" | while read -r f ; do
   echo $f : $(grep -ow XYZ "$f" | wc -l)
done
```

Comment: I tried that before but I am not sure how to use `grep` with `wc` along with `find`, can you tell me how?